# Spring MVC -> Wicket Integration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, wicket

I'm working on porting part of an existing Spring MVC application over to Wicket.

I used the wicket-spring library to get the initial integration working, but now I'm stuck with the best way to integrate my Spring Security implementation.

I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check [Wicket / Swarm / Spring Security How-to](http://out-println.blogspot.com/2009/02/wicket-swarm-spring-security-how-to.html)?

Comment: I tried looking into it a bit more, but wicketstuff.org is down right. Does anyone have any idea on how to get a hold of the admin? It's been down for like 3-4 days.

Comment: Good to know a nice article about Wicket-Spring security integration (+1)

Comment: @Arthur Glad you found it interesting (I did too :)